# I am not getting the correct value for kilograms

Tags: python, if-statement

I just made a simple weight converter that can take the input from user and convert that to kg or lbs. I didn't got any error but I run the code it just says the value in lbs not in kg... Please help me out... Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Also: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

````
weight=int(input("Ceki gir : "))

kg=weight*2.20
lbs=weight/2.20

type1=input("K for kG P for p ")
    
if type1=="P" or type1=="p":
    print("Your weight is: ",lbs)
elif type1=="K" or type1=="k":
    print("Your weight is: ",kg)
else:
    print("Wrong")```

I wrote like this and i think it is worked u can try and tell me if it is worked or not
````